# How can I get Mathematica 11 logo?

Tags: plotting, polyhedra

I want to get the picture(it is better to get the equations) of the mathematica 11 logo, how can I achieve that? I have try alpha to solve this, sadly, it only give me mathematica 1 logo.[image]

I want to get this logo:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that logo exists in a rotatable 3D graphic. I think it's more of a graphic design, inspired by some form of a dodecahedron. I might be wrong though

Comment: I think mathematica maybe can genarate it...and I want to know who know that.

Comment: @user61054 You can get the polyhedra with `PolyhedronData["MathematicaPolyhedron"]`.

Comment: Although [this](http://blog.wolfram.com/2007/05/22/making-the-mathematica-6-spikey/) is the Mma 6 Spikey it might be useful.

Comment: See [`Spikey`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spikey.html)

Comment: You might try to get in touch with Michael and maybe he might have some ideas on how the Mathematica 11 Spikey was made, he wrote this blog entry in May 2007, so there is likely to be a lot more on how the other Mathematica spikey's were created. There are also several "Spikey" related demonstrations at Wolfram Demonstrations website at https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=spikey